# Disconnected TFS Server still lives on in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When starting VS 2012, I'm getting this error in the Output window:

```
> TF205020: Could not connect to server ‘https://Xxxxxxxx. This server was used in your last session, but it might be offline or unreachable. Confirm that the server is available on the network. To attempt to connect again, or to a different server, click ‘Connect To Team Foundation Server’ in Team Explorer or the Team menu.
> 
> The server returned the following error: TF400324: Team Foundation
> services are not available from server https://Xxxxxxx. Technical
> information (for administrator):   The underlying connection was
> closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure
> channel.
```

*(Xxxxx used for server name here).*

This is a TFS server I used on a contract project a couple of months ago - I'm no longer working with them so I want it just gone.  I removed the server in the Team / Connect to Team Foundation Server... dialog but this seems to live on in VS's memory somewhere.

Anyway to make it be gone/gone?

Comment: Doesn't this go away if you just connect to a new TFS?

Answer (score 3):

I (finally) was able to remove all my bindings and references to an old TFS server by doing the following:

1. Delete the contents of the folder, `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Cache`.
2. As someone else suggested, search for all occurrences of `LocalItemExclusions.config` within `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\`, and remove any/all "TeamProjectCollection" elements that reference the obsolete server in their `uri="..."` attribute.
3. Edit the file, `%LocalAppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\TeamExplorer\TeamExplorer.Config`.  Remove all "Server" elements having a url attribute that references the obsolete server.

I did this for both VS 2010 and VS2012.  It was not until I completed the third step that the error mentioned by the original poster went away, and Visual Studio started quickly, as it always used to.

Answer (score 2):

I was unwilling to use the nuclear option as described in the first part of [**superlime's** answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18772489/1633949) to this question--deleting the entire contents of *"%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\"*.

Instead I followed the second part of his answer--deleting the contents of *"%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\N.N\Cache"*, which I did for all versions (*N.N*) found.

That helped, but wasn't quite enough.   I also had to do the following:

- Search for all occurrences of a file called *LocalItemExclusions.config* within *"%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\"* and its subfolders.
- Remove from those files, in their entirety, any *<TeamProjectCollection>* elements that reference the obsolete server in their *uri="..."* attribute.

That was enough for me--however, I can imagine other references lurking, if you've been using TFS targeting that server for awhile.  If the above steps are insufficient, you might simply try searching for additional references in all files (excluding logs) in that directory hierarchy, and surgically removing them.

Answer (score 2):

I found that I needed to do both steps to remove this from VS 2012 :

1. Delete the content of the folder `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Cache`
2. Delete the content of the folder `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\`

Much thanks to both contributors for their help.  Shame to Microsoft for not insuring that removing Team Foundation occurs cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a "nuke from orbit" option, but try deleting the contents of the TFS client cache.  Should be located in this location:

```
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\
```

According to [this blog post](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2012/08/19/how-to-clear-visual-studio-team-explorer-cache.aspx) (which is for 2010, and a little stale on version info), you should just delete the *contents* of the cache folder, not the cache folder itself (or the parent dir)..  So theoretically you'd just want to delete everything inside of:

```
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache
```